# Can't change default language in android developer console - Missing non-existent in-app product translations

Tags: android, google-console-developer

I have an app with default language which is not English. I want it to be English. When I try to change the default language from **Store listing > Manage translations > Set as default** the following error appears

***"Before you can change language to English (United States), you need to provide English (United States) translations for all your in-app products. Translations are currently missing for 9 products."***

The thing is that we no longer have in-app products. As you can see from the image. [image]

The other problem is that **Google support** is **helpless** and despite the numerous emails and live chats they always need "more time" to investigate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The store in-app products visibility is connected to having a billing permission in the last APK. So I had to add another APK with BILLING permission and the in-app products became visible. Before that, I thought we don't have in-app products. I've added translations for them because active subscriptions can't be deleted. After adding translations for all products I managed to change the default language of the store listing.

Comment: This is ANNOYING. Had the same problem.